# Why not correct check "is"?

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso

Here Kotlin's snippet:

```
fun withBackgroundColorResId(@IdRes expectedId: Int): Matcher<Any> {

        return object : BoundedMatcher<Any, Any>(Any::class.java) {
            override fun matchesSafely(view: Any): Boolean {
                if (view !is View || view !is ViewGroup) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "withBackgroundColorResId_incorrect_type, view = $view")
                    return false
                }
                val currenColor = (view.background.current as ColorDrawable).color
                val expectedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(view.context, expectedId)
                return currenColor == expectedColor
            }

            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                description.appendText("textView with background color resId: ")
                description.appendValue(context.getResources().getString(expectedId))
            }
        }
}
```

and usage:

```
onView(withRecyclerView(tradersRecyclerView).atPositionOnView(traderCheckPos, pauseTextView)).check(matches(withBackgroundColorResId(trade_not_running_color)))
```

and here logcat:

```
06-05 10:25:12.787 I/ViewInteraction(22053): Checking 'MatchesViewAssertion{viewMatcher=textView with background color resId: "#ffbde6ff"}' assertion on view RecyclerView with id: com.myproject.debug:id/tradersRecyclerView at position: 0
06-05 10:25:12.787 W/com.myproject.custom.matcher.CustomMatchers(22053): withBackgroundColorResId_incorrect_type, view = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{a412c35 V.ED..C.. ........ 0,0-288,288 #7f0800c9 app:id/pauseTextView}
06-05 10:25:12.794 D/com.myproject.activity.TradersActivityTest(22053): afterEach
06-05 10:25:12.794 I/MockWebServer(22053): MockWebServer[8081] done accepting connections: Socket closed
06-05 10:25:12.825 D/LifecycleMonitor(22053): Lifecycle status change: com.myproject.ui.activity.TradersActivity@2964795 in: PAUSED
06-05 10:25:12.825 D/LifecycleMonitor(22053): running callback: androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$LifecycleCallback@9705558
06-05 10:25:12.825 D/LifecycleMonitor(22053): callback completes: androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$LifecycleCallback@9705558
```

as you can see the object "**view**" has type `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView`. As we known `AppCompatTextView` is extends from `View`

But why it print

```
withBackgroundColorResId_incorrect_type, view = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin's documentation `is` states:

> checks that a value has a certain type

So according to Your code, You ask in a way

> is my view instance of X?

Following this line You get:

1. is `view instanceof View`? Answer is yes.
2. is `view instanceof ViewGroup`? Answer is no.

Single views extends mainly by View class. ViewGroups are mostly used in more complex layouts like `LinearLayout`,`FrameLayout`, etc.

Concluding the results, You have:

`true||false` = true

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your if condition, as the view is not a ViewGroup the condition is always true thus will print the LOG.

```
if (view is View) {
     Log.w(TAG, "withBackgroundColorResId_incorrect_type, view = $view")
     return false
}
```

Please, try with this one and see the outcome.